# SwiftUI add view to NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, navigationview

I'm currently working on rewriting a VoIP app from UIKit to SwiftUI. In the UIKit version, we have an active call screen with a button that when tapped, closes the active call screen and lets you interact with the app. Tapping this button also adds a view to the UINavigationController, basically covers most of the navigation view and when tapped, returns the user back to the active call screen.

I'm experimenting with different ideas in SwiftUI, but haven't hit on any solid ideas yet and wanted to see if the community had any ideas for accomplishing this.

Here's a sample of what the UIKit code:

```
class MainNavController: UINavigationController {
  func showActiveCallBar() {
    ...
    let activeCallBarView = ...
    ...
    view.addSubview(activeCallBarView)
  }
}
```

Here's a gif of what happens when we switch back and forth, sorry, couldn't show the whole app. You can see the whole upper portion of the Navigation View gets covered.

[image: return to call button]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, we would accomplish something like this with an `@State` variable, which would track wether we want to show the active call bar.

When your state variable changes, your SwiftUI view will be updated and the active call bar will be shown or hidden. It might look something like this.

```
struct PlayButton: View {
    @State private var showActiveCallBar: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        if (showActiveCallBar) {
            ActiveCallBarView()
        }

        // ... Other Views
    }
}
```

The SwiftUI documentation of [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) has more helpful information, and the SwiftUI docs generally are quite helpful in this regard. You could start with the SwiftUI tutorials https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui